# when i'm install laravel by composer have an warning

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8

have an warning like this when i'm installing larevl 8 by composer. i don't know will this affect the project that will be created?

https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (The "https://repo.packagist.org/p2/phar-io/manifest~dev.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

i don't know if this affects the projects that will be made so i didn't do anything.

Comment: Why not try it out and see whether it affects your project or not? Looks like a network problem to me